# Angular update object in array on ng-click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On the snippet below each cell contains the name of a shape that are taken from a given sequence. I'm trying to update the shape name of the selected cell on ng-click="fadeName(card)", however, when clicking it does update all cells with the same shape name.For instance, if you click row1,col1 which is by default square, all other squares will be updated, I only want to update the selected one. How can I update only the selected cell value ?

```js
// constant variables 
var constants = new (function() {
    var rows = 10;
    var columns = 10;
    this.getRows = function() { return rows; };
    this.getColumns = function() { return columns; };
   
})();

// Global Variables
var shapeSequence = 
  [
    {id: '1', name:'square'},
    {id: '2', name:'triangle'},
    {id: '3', name:'circle'},
    {id: '4', name:'oval'},
    {id: '5', name:'pentagon'},
    {id: '6', name:'hexagon'},
    {id: '7', name:'decagon'},
  ]


// this function creates deck of cards that returns an object of cards 
function createDeck() {
 var rows = constants.getRows();
 var cols = constants.getColumns();
 var key = createColors();
  
 var deck = {};
 deck.rows = [];

 // create each row
 for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = {};
  row.cards = [];
  
  // creat each card in the row
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   var card = {};
   card.item = key.shift();
   row.cards.push(card);
  }
  deck.rows.push(row);
 }
 return deck;
}


function createColors() {
 var coloredCards = [];
 
  var rows = constants.getRows();
 var cols = constants.getColumns();

  var cells = rows * cols;
 for (var n = 0; n < cells; n++) {
    var thisCard = shapeSequence[n % shapeSequence.length];
    coloredCards.splice(n, 0, thisCard);
 }
  
 return coloredCards;
 
} 

var app = angular.module('cards', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller("CardController", function($scope) {
 $scope.deck = createDeck();
  $scope.fadeName = function(card) {
    card.item.name = 'black';
  }
  
  
});
```

```css
.card_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1; 
  font-size: 1em;
  border:solid 1px;
  border-color:black;

}

.card_container {
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
} 

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


table {
 margin: 0px auto;
  
}

.cntr {
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="cards">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="cntr" ng-controller="CardController">
  <table >
   <tr ng-repeat="row in deck.rows">
    <td ng-repeat="card in row.cards">
     <div class="card_container " >
      <div class="card " ng-click="fadeName(card)"  ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false" >
              <p ng-if="hover"> {{card.item.name}} </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While pushing to row

do

```
card = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(card));
row.cards.push(card);
```

Answer (score 0):

You added reference from shapeSequence into your cells where you updated one cells data that will reflect everywhere where you used the same reference. So I only created clone while creating colors in 'createColors()'. clone() is also added.

```js
// constant variables 
var constants = new (function() {
    var rows = 10;
    var columns = 10;
    this.getRows = function() { return rows; };
    this.getColumns = function() { return columns; };
   
})();

function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

// Global Variables
var shapeSequence = 
  [
    {id: '1', name:'square'},
    {id: '2', name:'triangle'},
    {id: '3', name:'circle'},
    {id: '4', name:'oval'},
    {id: '5', name:'pentagon'},
    {id: '6', name:'hexagon'},
    {id: '7', name:'decagon'},
  ]


// this function creates deck of cards that returns an object of cards 
function createDeck() {
 var rows = constants.getRows();
 var cols = constants.getColumns();
 var key = createColors();
  
 var deck = {};
 deck.rows = [];

 // create each row
 for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = {};
  row.cards = [];
  
  // creat each card in the row
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   var card = {};
   card.item = key.shift();
   row.cards.push(card);
  }
  deck.rows.push(row);
 }
 return deck;
}


function createColors() {
 var coloredCards = [];
 
  var rows = constants.getRows();
 var cols = constants.getColumns();

  var cells = rows * cols;
 for (var n = 0; n < cells; n++) {
    var thisCard = shapeSequence[n % shapeSequence.length];
    coloredCards.splice(n, 0, clone(thisCard));
 }
  
 return coloredCards;
 
} 

var app = angular.module('cards', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller("CardController", function($scope) {
 $scope.deck = createDeck();
  $scope.fadeName = function(card) {
    card.item.name = 'black';
  }
  
  
});
```

```css
.card_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1; 
  font-size: 1em;
  border:solid 1px;
  border-color:black;

}

.card_container {
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
} 

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


table {
 margin: 0px auto;
  
}

.cntr {
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="cards">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="cntr" ng-controller="CardController">
  <table >
   <tr ng-repeat="row in deck.rows">
    <td ng-repeat="card in row.cards">
     <div class="card_container " >
      <div class="card " ng-click="fadeName(card)"  ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false" >
              <p ng-if="hover"> {{card.item.name}} </p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 </div>
</html>
```